# EntityFramework.Utilities insert all records with a entity reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework.Utilities to insert records on my MVC project.

Here is the website about EntityFramework.Utilities:

https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities

The method that I used is

```
EFBatchOperation.For(context, context.entityName).InsertAll(listItem);
```

It works and it's fast, however it doesn't allow me to have a entity reference in the listItem, it throw an SQLexception said "Login dailed for user, this session has been assigned a tracing id xxxx-xxxx. It happens when I use the same context to find the BatchTransfer and use the EFBatchOperation to insert the records.

Here's my code:

```
            try
        {
            //create the context
            ParkingLotContext context = new ParkingLotContext().Sql();
            BatchTransfer batch = context.BatchTransfers.Where(w => w.Id == pBatch.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            List<UnParsedRecord> unParsedList = new List<UnParsedRecord>();
            foreach (var item in CsvFile.Read<UnParsedRecord>(pUploadPath))
            {
                item.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                item.BatchTransfer = batch;
                item.ParseState = "UnParsed";
                unParsedList.Add(item);
            }

            EFBatchOperation.For(context, context.UnParsedRecords).InsertAll(unParsedList); //this line throws exception because i'm using the same context
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = string.Concat("Unable to add batch transfer record into database. ", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
```

After that, I tried to create a new context just for the insertAll method:

```
try
        {
            ParkingLotContext context = new ParkingLotContext().Sql();
            EFBatchOperation.For(context, context.UnParsedRecords).InsertAll(unParsedList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
```

This time it didn't gave me error but the batchTransfer foreign key(Guid) didn't set(It shows all 0)

How can I fix this or is there a way to get the record by using the EntityFramework.Utilities? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this question. I'm sorry I didn't see it earlier.

The first error is solved in a recent update. The older versions didn't work with unless you used windows authentication or specified in the connection string that EF should keep the login info. But as I said, that one is solved if you use a newer version.

For the second problem you have to understand that EFUtilities works very "sqlish". By that I mean it really works best if your entity has the foreign key as a proprty (like the sql table does). Then you would do

`item.BatchTransferId = batch.Id;`

I wish I had seen it earlier but hopefully it might help you or someone else in the future. To catch my attention i might be better to post a link to the SO question as an issue on Github page.